# Relation between VCO's (Voltage Controled Oscillator's) Frequency and Voltage

Tags: oscillator, frequency, vco

I have a question that what is the relationship between the VCO generated frequency and applied volatage. Is there any formula which we can use to find the applied voltage and get the frequency generated against it?
And thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a particular vco or implementation in mind? The answer at present is: it depends. Some are linear, some are logarithmic, some are different all together

Answer (score 1):

VCOs are made with various technologies for various purposes, so the answer is 'it depends'.

Some low frequency VCOs are intended to have very linear relationship, perhaps to be used as a voltage to frequency converter. They often turn the input voltage into a current, to swing the voltage on a capacitor over a fixed range. This sort of architecture departs from linearity at low frequency, when fixed leakage currents become a significant part of the controlled current, and at high frequency, when switching propagation times become a significant part of the output period. Without the intention to have a linear relationship, VCOs may well depart significantly from nominal linearity.

There is a class of VCO that sacrifices frequency linearity for period linearity, using a constant current to swing a capacitor between voltages dependent on the input. Here the propagation delay time is an additive constant onto the period, leakage currents are with respect to a fixed current, and a t=mV+c straight line can be accurately defined between input voltage and output period.

High frequency VCOs for RF work usually use varactors in LC oscillators. These designs are not usually driven by thoughts of linearity, but noise, spectral purity, and 'oh, if it's not too nonlinear, that would be handy!' Although the capacitance is a very nonlinear function of the applied voltage, the fact that frequency varies as the square root of capacitance means that even in wide range VCOs, the change in FM sensitivity across the range can end up being quite small, often less than a factor of 2.

The best measurement-grade voltage to frequency converter I have come across used a 4046 PLL fed back with a frequency discriminator based on a HC123 monostable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a integrated circuit chip VCO then you need to look at the part data sheet. They may provide a formula for the control voltage to frequency relationship. More likely there will be a graph shown that shows the relationship in a normalized manner. (Normalized because many IC chip VCOs can support a range for nominal frequencies dependent upon externally attached components. Note also that the control voltage to frequency transfer function is likely to not be a linear relationship.

If you are designing your own VCO from discrete components then the control voltage relationship is going to be full dependent upon the circuit design. In this case you can either try to apply basic electronics circuit analysis or as most folks do these days they characterize the circuit behavior with a circuit simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Wideband VCO's are very non-linear, but in limited range may be selected in [MHz/V].
Narrowband VCO's can  be very linear with careful design.
Very narrowband VCXO's are stable Xtal controlled.
VC-TCXO are also temperature compensated.

VCO's are used in PLL and Synth IC's for example.

Here are a [few.](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/clock-timing-clock-generators-plls-frequency-synthesizers/728?k=vco&k=&pkeyword=vco&pv7=243&FV=1f140000%2Cffe002d8&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=1&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500)